# Im unable to start server using django python manage.py runserver. Im getting the below error

Tags: django, mongodb, ssl, ssl-certificate, pymongo

raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-02.gtkp9.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125),cluster0-shard-00-01.gtkp9.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125),cluster0-shard-00-00.gtkp9.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 60c1c8dc887aed978363ee86, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.gtkp9.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-00.gtkp9.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.gtkp9.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-01.gtkp9.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.gtkp9.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-02.gtkp9.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)')>]>

Comment: Please give some more info... where are you trying this...DEV or PROD server...?? are you deploying for the first time...?? what settings have you used for SSL...??

Comment: M trying this on command prompt in windows 10

Comment: M not deploying it anywhere. Im trying to run locally'

Comment: have you installed openssl...?? and why to use ssl in local development server...??

Comment: I used this command export SSL_CERT_FILE=$(pypy -c "import certifi; print(certifi.where())") in git bash. The file is running in git bash. But it is not running in cmd

Comment: Actually Im connecting to mongodb